# Don't add diet tags to questions that aren't about a diet pattern

Tags: discussion, tags, announcement

In my zealous pursuit of good tagging I've gone too far and made an error. I added [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) to questions that don't really need it, and in fact are probably better off without it. Dropping the veganism tag makes the question applicable to a wider audience, like this:

- [dairy-substitutes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy-substitutes) [Which Canadian pizza chain restaurants offer dairy-free cheese?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/which-canadian-pizza-chain-restaurants-offer-dairy-free-cheese)
- [dairy-substitutes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy-substitutes) [Which plant-based milks have the highest protein content?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/which-plant-based-milks-have-the-highest-protein-content)

Neither of those questions are specific to veganism, despite the fact that they were asked by a vegan (me). These questions would be equally interesting to an ovo-vegetarian or somebody with a milk allergy or any other reason for wanting to avoid dairy products.

On the other hand, there are many cases where it's beneficial to add a diet-specific tag onto a question because a really good answer needs to fit within that diet. Here are a few examples done right.

- [raw](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw) [Raw food veganism - maintaining energy levels as an older athlete](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/raw-food-veganism-maintaining-energy-levels-as-an-older-athlete)
- [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) [Would vegans eat fruits with worms?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/606/would-vegans-eat-fruits-with-worms)
- [lacto-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-vegetarianism) [Why is egg commonly allowed in vegetarian food?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/418/why-is-egg-commonly-allowed-in-vegetarian-food)
- [lacto-ovo-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-ovo-vegetarianism) [Vegetarian foods in Japanese culture?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/417/vegetarian-foods-in-japanese-culture)
- [fruitarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruitarianism) [What is a good source of thiamine (B1), niacin (B3) and B12 for fruitarians?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/185/what-is-a-good-source-of-thiamine-b1-niacin-b3-and-b12-for-fruitarians)

In each case the question author is searching for answers that fit within a particular lifestyle/diet pattern. In order to answer the questions in the most helpful and succinct way, it's useful to know what restrictions the author has in mind. Without this clarity, answers lose focus and end up trying to cover all possible bases. Or worse, answers might begin to look like advocacy. Jon Ericson◆ [provided](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/184/1236) us with this amazing quote from Robert on Christianity.

> If this site is going to succeed, it is absolutely essential that questions be answered specifically within the context of the belief system they are asked. This is not optional or reserved for the people you agree with; It is a basic tenet of the site.

I don't have a question, I'm just sharing a cautionary tale for other would-be tag editors.

Comment: I appreciate the attention to detail that you've been bringing to tags -- such curating only makes the site better :)